# WorldRenderer responsibilities

Tags: libgdx

I started learning libgdx lately and, obviously, I've been looking into several sample games and tutorials.

I couldn't help but notice inconsistencies into how authors/developers choose to design their game classes - especially when it comes to the "renderer" classes.

In some examples, I see some authors relying solely on the "renderer" classes to draw using the SpriteBatch. While others tend to send a SpriteBatch reference to game objects to do the rendering themselves.

For example, considering a *Bird* class, some would associate it with a *Texture* type, load it and render the bird inside a *Bird.render* method. Others load the *Texture* in separate "*Renderer*" classes (Like *WorldRenderer*) and draw the bird texture from there by relying on position parameters such as bird.getX() and bird.getY().

I wrote some sample games using XNA in the past and I used to embed the rendering logic into my game classes. My renderer class used to simply loop over all "enabled" game objects and call "GameObject.render()".  Is this a bad practice in libgdx?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not about bad practice *in libgdx*, it's a general opinion oriented problem.

Usually, it's always better if you can separate game logic and rendering logic (preferably in different classes). This way, if you want to change look and feel of the game (re-skin it) later, you won't have to touch the code containing game logic (less testing required, no new bugs).

But not everyone follows this (some might think it as overkill for small things). Having renderer class for each and every small thing might seem too much. So you'd see a lot of code having mixed both rendering and game logic.

If you want to build scalable games, I'd suggest you to follow MVC (game codes so large that developers might get lost). But at the same time, you should be pragmatic enough to know when not to use it (small games taking 2 weeks to make).

So it's for you to decide really, since it's about personal preferences.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

A lot probably depends if the developer has used MVC (Model-View-Controller) before. In an MVC design the "game" objects like bird are part of the model and don't directly have anything to do with the display(view). Sometimes it depends on the technologies being used, for instance the LibGDX Scene2d API warns you that "Scene graphs have the drawback that they couple model and view".

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I use MVC heavily and I know exactly what you're talking about. But it makes you wonder, if popular libraries like Scene2D couple Model and View - is it really such a bad practice? I don't see that benefits are 100% comparable in the gaming world. For example, in MVC "Web Designer" can build the views by himself with no need for extensive programming experience... I don't see how this can be applicable in game development?

Comment: In a game an important part of the data is where something is located at in the world and how big it is. In most web pages it doesn't matter where the form/data is displayed. So that makes the game model a little harder to separate from the rendering. BUT think about trying to create multiple versions of your doodle/super jumper clone. If you have Bunny Hopper and Death Escaper it might be easier to reskin the entire app if the rendering was separate.

Answer (score 0):

In a worldRenderer you should render all your objects. All your objects belongs to a world so it makes sense. A benefit to add attention to is that you can always keep all gameObjects in separate arrays aswell as in a big array (containing all).

`Array: GameObjects
Array: Birds (also in GameObjects)
Array: Cows (also in GameObjects)
Array: Cats (also in GameObjects)`

This makes it possible for you to decide on what "z" axis all gameobjects should rely on (render) aswell as just loop through them all right away (update)